# How to migrate React app to React Router in order to retrieve parameters from path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a fully functional React web-app that now has a new requirement of loading separate images based on the URL suffix. It seems that in order to retrieve any information from the path I need to have a React Router App. Is there ---
A: A way to easily migrate to React Router so I can use this.props.location.pathname? 
or B: Another way to retrieve the pathname without migrating to React Router.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using react-router to do only that would be overkill. You can easily retrieve the url path with `window.location.pathname`. What you should is setup a listener on the location that sets the pathname to state and you can pass it down to the components that need it.

```
  window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
         console.log('location changed!');
  }
```